# Checking jQuery.ajax different states

Tags: jquery, ajax

How can I check the status of an AJAX request with jQuery? In normal AJAX we can do this:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'different state'?

Comment: What do you mean by different state? Do you mean whether the request was successful or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$.ajax()` method in jQuery has both `success` and `error` handlers depending on the state of the response.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/controller/action/",
    data: myVariable,
    success: function(data) {
        alert("It worked");
        // do something with data
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert("It didn't work");
        // Error handling.
    }
});
```